# Why sort in a list doesn't work?

Tags: python, python-2.7

The snippet is below:

```
s = set()
s.add("Banana")
s.add("Apple")
s.add("Pear")
s.add("Strawberry")
```

I want to sort the set to a list. so I'm using below code:

```
l = list(s).sort()
```

But the `l` is `None`. If I separate the line to two as below:

```
l2 = list(s)
l2.sort()
```

Then it works. My question is why the first one failed?

Comment: Your latter sample (`l = l.sort(key=str.lower)`) *also* 'doesn't work'.

Comment: @MartijnPieters sorry, i update my code. btw, i think this is different from the link you provide.

Comment: You did not; you still do `l = l.sort()`, assigning `None` to `l`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters for the latter sample,  i only do `l2.sort()` not `l2=l2.sort()`. it's updated.

Comment: You do now, when I got your comment the update wasn't there yet.

Comment: And this is *definitely* a dupe.

Comment: @MartijnPieters your link is quite helpful for me. but in my case, `list(s)` will return a list, then why call the `sort()` immediately, it doesn't work, if you separate the code, then it works.

Comment: Read my answer **more carefully**. `list.sort()` returns `None`. It is the result of **that method** that is stored, not the `list(s)` expression.

Comment: @MartijnPieters got it. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

`list.sort` sorts in-place. If you want to sort and return the sorted list you can use `sorted(list)` instead.

You could change your code to something like the following.

```
sorted_list = sorted(s, key=str.lower)
```